# failed conversion with TopoJSON

Tags: json, command-line, npm, topojson

After installing `topojson` with `sudo npm install -g topojson` I am unable to convert neither a shapfile (.shp) nor a geojson file to a topojson file.

```
Alexanders-MacBook-Pro:topojson alexander$ geo2topo Parcel11_projected.geojson > Parcel11_topo.json
buffer.js:495
    throw new Error('"toString()" failed');
    ^

Error: "toString()" failed
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:495:11)
    at Object.parse (native)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/bin/geo2topo:107:46)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
Alexanders-MacBook-Pro:topojson alexander$ topojson -q 1e4 -o out.json --Parcel11Cert.shp
-bash: topojson: command not found
```

It seems that the code is executed in the first case but the geojson is too large to convert.  In the second case, the command is not recognized.

I am using the following [command line reference](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-1.x-api-reference/blob/master/Command-Line-Reference.md)

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Already answered in [Large geoJSON to TopoJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514816/large-geojson-to-topojson). Summary: File is too large to be processed by the js engine, error message is unfortunate.